# Android: Isolated 'ClassNotFoundException' reported in Dev Console

Tags: android, classloader, classnotfoundexception, runtimeexception

My app has been live on the Play Store for a little while now and has around 500 installs, today I was greeted by the following in my Dev Console's ANR & Crashes section:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6423)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6012)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5951)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3 (ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1710)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6408)
```

There are 6 of these reports (all identical) from one user, using Android Version 7 on a Galaxy S8+ (dream2qltesq).

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

I've ruled out the 64k method reference limit and/or Proguard being the cause, because (and please correct me if I'm wrong), I would have throught that if it were the 64k method reference limit, I would get errors when building the app in Android Studio (which I don't) and if Proguard were the cause, I would assume this problem would show itself every time a production build was installed and run (which it doesn't).

There are a few similar errors mentioned in questions here on SO, but they are usually of the "runs fine from Eclipse/Android Studio, but doesn't run when installed from the Play Store' variety.  I know my app works from the Play Store, so am a little perplexed as to why this might show up for just one user out of 500.  I've not seen this problem before and have not been able to re-create it.

I would appreciate if anyone has experience with these types of crash reports/exceptions, and if there is anything I can do to rectify the problem.

Comment: Hi Yvette, target SDK version is 25

Answer (score 0):

Once in my app the problem was in incorrect MultiDex implementation, I solve it after add to main class MultiDex.install(this);

```
public class MyMainClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MultiDex.install(this);
...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oleg, If it was a multiDex issue would it not show up every time anyone tried to run it and not just intermittently? Also, would it not show an error/warning at build time? thanks.

Comment: Hi @Zippy, as I remember, I did not get any warning and errors due build time and I've got only runtime crash on some SDK versions